# Mixed https and http or pure https for google?

Tags: http, https, protocols

Me and my colleague have a little discussion about the [HTTPS as a ranking signal](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hu/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html) topic.

Because we want to serve google what we can, we decided, we will buy a certificate.

At this point my colleague sad, now let's change all the external resources links for example (to our CDN) `//` instead of `https`, so now users can access our page both `http` or `https`.

I told to him, do not do this, let's use `https` everywhere, and in the `.htaccess` redirect all the http requests to https.

Let's say, our cdn is now on `http://cdn.example.com`.

I say, let's write `https://cdn.example.com`, while my colleague say use `//cdn.example.com`.

What is your experience with this, what is the recommendation to incrase google page rank?

I know, it's a littlebit opinion based, but maybe you have argument for one or for the other.

Comment: An opinion on the topic: https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Comment: Certainly if you have a page served as https://*what.ever* then all the resources (scripts, forms, images, css, etc) on that page should also be https or else browsers will show worrying messages to your users.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter to be honest. Google will rank **YOUR** pages - not the resources your pages use (assuming you're not using insecure content on your https version or your will likely be ranked down).

On the one side there is a slight performance hit from using https so using // will benefit your http pages ever so slightly, and there is no real benefit to using the https versions when your main page is served over http rather than https. Also some ad networks also serve different (or more variety of) ads over http rather than https if some of the providers haven't supplied a https version (I'd imagine this is rare none but haven't got/looked up any stats to back up this opinion).

On the other hand I would say better to use https:// everywhere as it will be easier to find problems if any page has an issue with serving an https version, rather than managing two versions.l and check both.

A bigger problem is why this is even an issue?

Are you planning on allowing your site to be accessed over both http and https? Then you will have a duplicate content problem and Google will likely decide which side is the definitive one (likely decide on which version is linked to most) and hence you may not gain any ranking boost (which will be a small one btw) like you hope.

Alternatively are you planning on offering some of your site over http and some (e.g. the logged in pages) over https? In that case using the // format will mean the CDN content needs to be downloaded again when in https mode, whereas using the https:// format will mean the same resources are used for both and don't require downloading again. And of course you won't get the ranking boost again for the non-https pages.

IMHO it is **much** better to use https **only** on your site, and redirect http traffic to https. It simplifies everything and also means it doesn't matter which you use (// or https://) - though again my preference would be to use https just to be sure - and as a matter of personal taste.